# query the google play store for the version of an app?

Tags: android, google-play

is there a way to query the play store for the version of an app without the need for user-credentials. I am aware of this unofficial API:

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

but I don't want to rely on user credentials - I can visit the google play sites in incognito mode via chrome also - so it must be possible somehow. But I found no way and I don't want to fallback on scraping ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking my app version programmatically in Android market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091534/checking-my-app-version-programmatically-in-android-market)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a suitable API via G+:
this is the API: https://androidquery.appspot.com

example call: https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=org.ligi.fast

and this wrapper/code: https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery

Comment: this api is hosted on google app engine which may outage when daily free quota used up.

Comment: @ligi can you explain how does the example work i mean which api its uses??

Comment: Can i use this https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=org.ligi.fast link. Is it reliable for future use??

Comment: Nice. Now if it would just return more meta information, like an icon, average rating, etc.

Comment: This api is stop working after few request, it is not reliable.

Comment: @Lavekush Yea - they get over quota now sometimes - might not have been such a wise idea to advertise it here ;-)

Comment: Traffic is so high that I get very few requests with any positive return.

Comment: This service is dead, 2017

Answer (score 0):

Also check out:  [www.playstoreapi.com](http://www.playstoreapi.com)

It's unofficial but easy to use (free for non commercial use). you can get data about apps, search the play store and get top charts data. from their documentation section:

Node.js:

```
var request     = require('request');
var apiKey      = 'wij5czxu3mxkzkt9'; // your API key
var packageName = 'com.whatsapp';     // package Name, e.g. com.whatsapp for WhatsApp

var url = 'http://api.playstoreapi.com/v1.1/apps/' + packageName + '?key=' + apiKey;

request({
    url: url,
    json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the json response
    }
});
```

HTML/JS:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<p></p>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  var apiKey = 'wij5czxu3mxkzkt9'; // your API key
  var app    = 'com.whatsapp';     // package com.whatsapp for WhatsApp

  var url = 'http://api.playstoreapi.com/v1.1/apps/' + app + '?key=' + apiKey;

  $.getJSON(url).done(function(appDetails) {
    $('p:last').html(JSON.stringify(appDetails));
  });

  </script>
</body>
</head>
<html>
```

Python:

```
import urllib2
import json

packageName = 'com.whatsapp'      # package com.whatsapp for WhatsApp
apiKey      = 'wij5czxu3mxkzkt9'  # your API key

url = 'http://api.playstoreapi.com/v1.1/apps/{0}?key={1}'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url.format(packageName, apiKey))

data = json.load(response)   
print data
```

C# .NET:

```
string apiKey = "wij5czxu3mxkzkt9"; // your API key
string app    = "com.whatsapp";     // package com.whatsapp for WhatsApp

string url = "http://api.playstoreapi.com/v1.1/apps/{0}?key={1}";

using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
    string jsonString = webClient.DownloadString(string.Format(url, app, apiKey));
}
```

Comment: www.playstoreapi.com is not available anymore and maybe if someone still needs to use then he can give a try to https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API/

Comment: From where you got the appkey?

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that nowadays a lot of apps have multiple versions running. For those apps with one version you can try [42matters Lookup API](https://42matters.com/api/lookup?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=36359819), it should give you the correct version.

Comment: Interesting but really expensive

Comment: It is a paid api and it is not cheap. I would use jsoup instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates