# Update app which was installed using other app, via Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app which has the function of install others apps when the user request for it. But it does not redirects the user to Play Store, just download the apk and installs it. When I do that, the Play Store recognize it has been installed if I search for it using the Search Bar, but it does not show the app in "My apps", and does not update this installed apps when there is any update.

What I want to know is, there is a way of check for update for theses apps on the Play Store, and update them? Or, if there is any way of check if there is any update in the Play Store and notify the user to update.

All the apps installed by my application are free in Play Store.

Comment: This sounds like an app that violates section 4.5 of the [Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html).

Comment: @Tanis.7x IANAL - but IMHO only when he distributes via play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might use the api from androidquery - here an example call:

```
https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=org.ligi.fast
```

more info here: [query the google play store for the version of an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470402/query-the-google-play-store-for-the-version-of-an-app)