# Unable to check the latest version on Play Store

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have two APKs added to the Play Store with the same version code. one for the devices which have SIM slot, and the other one for devices don't having SIM slot. 
I am using below code to check the latest verision on Play Store :

```
Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName()/* + "&hl=en"*/)
```

But getting error due to two different APKs on Play Store. Also tried [AppUpdater](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker)  without any success.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309564/how-to-get-app-market-version-information-from-google-play-store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking my app version programmatically in Android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091534/checking-my-app-version-programmatically-in-android-market)

Comment: Use this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823475/how-to-get-latest-version-of-android-app-from-google-playstore?answertab=active#tab-top "this text appears when you mouse over")!

Comment: It doesn't work.