# How to check app to avaible for new update?: android

Tags: android

I am new in `android` and i want to know how to check *programatically* if there is an update of my app from `play-store` or other apps market place.

Comment: Best of use these https://github.com/rampo/UpdateChecker , https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager

Answer (score 0):

If you have server deployed you can maintain the **versionCode** on them and check and compare it with your application on every launch. In case you have a static application you can refer to this post for solution [Check Play Store App VersionCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470402/query-the-google-play-store-for-the-version-of-an-app)

**EDIT 1**
If you need to get installed application version code and name

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Make a API call to your server get the latest released application version code.
Compare both version code, If obtained version code is greater than installed version - redirect/ ask user to update application via PlayStore.

Comment: @RaviVGHL Please accept the answer if this solved your problem. So that other member of community can be benefited.

Comment: that is not my account and question  bro