# How to get the app's latest version from Google play?

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I added my app to Google Play.

I want to pop up a dialog box to remind the user when the user launches the application, if there is a new update, the user can click "update" and then jump to Google Play.

I saw the following question, but unfortunately the answer is no longer working.

[How to get application version from google play?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40167639)

Google does not seem to provide any API to get the app version.

I am searching for a long time on net. Many answers are said to get the version number through Jsoup, but no use now.
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Here are the two methods I have tried：

（1）

```java
newVersionName = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                    .first()
                    .ownText();
```

（2）

```java
         Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get();

            if (document != null) {
                Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current\\sVersion");
                for (Element ele : element) {
                    if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                        Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                        for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                            newVersionName = sibElemet.text();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you try jsoup? Show your code

Comment: Hello @alice have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application

Comment: You can also use gpsversion checker library

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically check Play Store for app updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates)

Comment: Hello @AIK, the two methods I've tried have been re-added to the problem, and you can see them now, thanks.

Comment: Does it give any errors? If so then post the error log as well.

Comment: Hello @Nilesh, thanks, but what I want to get is the version number of my app on Google play.

Comment: Hello @Vivek, The gpsversion checker library seems to only support that updates via the app's server. but I want the user to jump to Google play to update. And I will read the documentation of this library again. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @ AIK, the compiler didn't throw any exceptions, but after I opened this address in my browser, Google play prompts me: "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server." This link: "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + <my app's package name> + "&hl=en"

Comment: Hello @AIK, the answer you provided is feasible. thank you very much!

Comment: I have used that library for fetching updates status from google play store

Comment: @alice glad to help.

Comment: Afaik there is no any official way to query Google Play to determine if you are running latest version or not. If you really need to do so, you must store version info somewhere else, for example in Firebase or your own server. I don't recommend any "unofficial" hacks, they may suddenly stop working or get blocked by Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method is possible: replace "Current\\sVersion" with "Current Version":

```
     Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();

        if (document != null) {
            Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
            for (Element ele : element) {
                if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                    Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                    for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                        newVersionName = sibElemet.text();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Good luck with that. As soon as Google changes Google Play website it won't work anymore.