# How to disable lower version of android applicaton in users' smartphone

Tags: android, version

I'm planning to release an application and later on release debug or edit version as well.

But what if I release my app version as 1.1, and I release the version 1.2 later on.
Then, there must be some people who downloaded new version 1.2, but others might still keep the version 1.1

1. Is there any way to disable the version 1.1 which is already installed in Users' smartphone?
2. Or.. is there any way to update the previous version 1.1 to the latest version 1.2 in users' smartphone automatically without any process??

As a matter of fact, I want all users to use my application's latest version in order to provide new adds/items to entire users.

If there's any way, please let me know!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't force users to upgrade to the newest version of your app. Really the best you can do is notify them that there is an update available for your app and encourage them to download it. [For that I would start here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091534/checking-my-app-version-programmatically-in-android-market)