# how to check if there is update to my app android

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to check each time a user launches my game, to notify him if there is an update to my app? Maybe there is something built into Google Play?

Comment: First step, use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create Simple web service.when user run your app check local version with server (app version in device and app version in server).
if app version is new , notify to user .

Answer (score 0):

Your answer was posted here:

[Checking my app version programmatically in Android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091534/checking-my-app-version-programmatically-in-android-market)

is a lib that get informations from a app in google play.