# How to get updated new version installed apps with my own android application with java language

Tags: java, android

I want to create android apps for listing installed apps in my mobile apps, but I want to create some validation check when google play store has a new update version. Is it possible from java to check update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201433/2775450)

It is similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a parser that checks Google Play web page and when an apps's version is different from the last check, it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out first, see how this works:
http://jsoup.org/
Pass this url to JSOUP - 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.package.name
Look for this tag:

```
<div class="meta-info"> 
<div class="title">Installs</div> <div class="content" itemprop="numDownloads">  1,000,000 - 5,000,000  </div> </div> <div class="meta-info"> <div class="title">Current Version</div> <div class="content" itemprop="softwareVersion"> 1.0  </div> </div> <div class="meta-info"> <div class="title">Requires Android</div> <div class="content" itemprop="operatingSystems">      2.2 and up    </div></div>
```

Pick up the version number here and compare it with the version currently installed. **voila!!**