# How to enable my android app to auto check for updates in the android market?

Tags: android

I have my android app already installed on devices and now I want that if I have released a new version of that app in the play store market then the app automatically detects that there is a new version available and notify the user that they can update the app. How can I do that?

Comment: do you have a dedicated server for your app ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically check Play Store for app updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates)

Answer (score 0):

you may create an api with json response to check version
and when update available simply redirect to google play store

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set this property in the application. You set this property in the [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en) in your application section like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This not official Api but it is working , Google will automatically give notification when app have new version on playstore, But if you want to force user to update app then you can implement [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/)

Answer (score 0):

The only case where you should be doing this is when your app uses a not packaged service (hosted on a server, in another app, etc).

This service should return an adequate response if the client (your app) is outdated. If you recieve such a response, then you can redirect to the play store.

---

If you don't use such a service and still want to do this, then check the [android market api](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/).

*But really, you shouldn't. The Play store already notifes the user if there is an update. No need to do that again, you will only annoy users.*

Answer (score 0):

when you upload your application's update version on google play store . Google play store automatically send notification to users for update version of your application.So no need to send user a custom notification for update version. So only set this functionality on your play store account