# how to show alert in already installed application if updated apk of that application is available on play store?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to show alert message popup in existing installed android application,after uploading new higher version's apk file for that application on goole play store is there any way to compare installed application version with new higher version of the play store's apk?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35969300/6503228)

Comment: no need to show alert in your application if you are using paly store, play store automatic show alert to user when you put new version of your application

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use GCM or FCM for all users. Send them the notification that the latest version of this app is available on app store.By doing this in one go you can tell all the users about new update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API for that.

There are some solutions.

1. You can try to parse the app's playstore detail page in the app and
   look for the version number then check it with the apps' version
2. Implement a server side version check system where you can check if a new update is available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you plz help me by providing such information like, Is there any API which returns the play store's app version for comparison?

Comment: You have to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want force update show alert then...

Firstly get your current application version then call a api for compare it and in response you should put for update message if meassage get then you can show alert to user.