# Getting app version of an beta from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, version, beta-testing

I'm developing an app which is already published as beta con Google Play, and I wrote a procedure to inform the users whether the installed version on their device is the same as the version on Google Play or if it needs to be updated. The problem is, the method I'm using doesn't seem to work for beta apps since it tries to access the **itemprop="softwareVersion"** tag on Google Play as a public user to get the info I need, and not everybody can access the info from my beta app, so I get a null value.

Is there any other way I could get the app version without publishing the production version of the app?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by itemprop="softwareVersion" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates

Comment: It may not work if you have multiple APK too. you would get Varies with device. I think Firebase Remote Config is a good option or API

Comment: @Ajay S  What I mean is I try to get the info from that tag, which is on the webpage with the app's details on Google Play.