# Programmatically check Play Store for app updates, may 2018

Tags: android

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates) has been asked before and **had** an answer. But Google changed something on their side and now it no longer works: the `softwareVersion` is no longer there.

### How to Programmatically check Play Store for app updates in may 2018?

---

Old Question and Answer:

[Programmatically check Play Store for app updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates)

[Old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35969300/4421627):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can get the version by parsing the html page of google play for that app?

Comment: that is the old way. But it seems to be not there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35969300/1848157 : isn't this solution working after may 2018 ?

Comment: @Radhey as far as I can tell not.

Comment: I have used that and its working but didn't check recently in the case of uploading new version of apps in last month :/

Answer (score -1):

please check this code

```java
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
```