# Android InApp Update not getting updates automatically

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update

I was considering Android InApp Update feature as an alternative solution for those clients who have turned off Auto-Updates from the PlayStore.

But I found it doesn't get the latest updates by itself. First I was considering that there's something bad in my code but later I found if I go to the PlayStore and fetch for the updates manually then it also shows me the update in my application.
If it's so then it's a useless feature or am I missing anything regarding this?

Comment: it only works with API level 21 above. Do you see any errors in logs?

Answer (score 0):

you cant update automatic but you can get the latest version of your app from playstore and show a dialog in your app to force update..   so when ever user open your app its show the update dialoge and you can also set this using api and check..
[Programmatically check Play Store for app updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates)

Comment: I have implemented all this and it's not working. Please reread my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your code here to verify if you are following everthing correctly. Meanwhile you can use this library to introduce in-app updates in your app. It's pretty simple to use and tested properly.

https://github.com/sohanzz/Easy-InApp-Updater