# Force to update apk on playstore

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Form mobile development, I created one apk and uploaded on Google Playstore.

> Apk current version = 12;
>
> Apk in mobile =11;

I want to compare my installed version of apk(11) with current version of apk on Playstore(12) and want to force to update apk.

I got coding for find installed version of apk by

```
Context context=this.ApplicationContext;
int code = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0).VersionCode;
```

How to find the current version of apk on playstore using xamarin c#. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official google api to get the version number of your app from playstore. [Programmatically check Play Store for app updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates)

To achieve this you can maintain a table in your server and whenever the user logs in you can check the current installed version with the version number in your server and if it does not match then call an intent to the playstore.

OR

[Android programmatically update application when a new version is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709443/android-programmatically-update-application-when-a-new-version-is-available)