# How to programmatically get the version of an app on Huawei AppGallery?

Tags: android, google-play, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I know how it can be done for Google Play Store [(answer here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309564/how-to-get-app-market-version-information-from-google-play-store), but i didn't manage to find a way for AppGallery.
Thank you!

**UPDATE #1**

Using the answer below i partially solve this with this steps:

1. Make an API Client with Administrator role, it also works with App Administrator and Operations. (documentaion here: [API Client](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-getstarted))
2. Get the access token. (documentaion here: [Obtaining a Token](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/obtain_token))
3. Get app info. (documentaion here: [Querying App Information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-app-info_query_v2))

The response from the Querying App Information, have a lot of informations about the app including "versionNumber", but for me it doesn't provide the "versionNumber" (the single info i needed), because this parameter is optional. And now i am stuck again, because i don't understand what i need to change in order to receive this one.

If anyone knows how I can solve this, thank you very much for your help.

**UPDATE #2**

@shirley's comment was right.
The issue has been fixed in their latest release, and it has been released this month.

Comment: i have edited your question to try make it more clear that you're looking for a solution through code, if you're unhappy with my changes feel free to change it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the Querying App Information API (GET mode) to query the app details：

```
public static void getAppInfo(String domain, String clientId, String token, String appId, String lang) {
     HttpGet get = new HttpGet(domain + "/publish/v2/app-info?appid=" + appId + "&lang=" + lang);
     get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
     get.setHeader("client_id", clientId);
     try {
         CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
         CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
         int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
         if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
             BufferedReader br =
                     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), Consts.UTF_8));
             String result = br.readLine();
             // Object returned by the app information query API, which can be received using the AppInfo object. For details, please refer to the API reference.
             JSONObject object = JSON.parseObject(result);
             System.out.println(object.get("ret"));
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
 }
```

They are mentioned here: [Completing App Information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-add_appinfo), [Querying App Information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-app-info_query_v2).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I made a API client  with administrator role, and made the request to Querying App Information,but the response doesn't have a "versionNumber".
In documentation it is written that "versionNumber" is optional, but how can i make it show in the request's response?

Comment: @Anna Could you please leave your appId? Let me check the info to see the problem. Besides, much basic information about apps created in AGC is empty by default. [Completing App Information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-add_appinfo) describes how to complete app information through the Publishing API.

Comment: The app id is 102606985. In documentation it is written that you can update multiple informations [(Updating Basic App Information)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-app-info_update_v2), but the "versionName" parameter isn't included.

Comment: @Anna Thank you for your contact. The issue has been fixed in their latest release, and it will be released by the end of August 2020.

Comment: HttpPost and HttpGet is already deprecated right?