# How get the app version on the play store

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, google-play-services

I want to know the app version on the android store for my app.

I need to know that to show to the user a message offering an update if it's necessary. I can get the app version of my installed version (using a cordova-plugin-app-version) like that:

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {

            console.log("la version de la app es " + version);
            $scope.versi = version;
});
```

but not the android store app version.

Comment: one way would be to make your own web service for checking what the current app version is

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The play store will offer the update anyhow when it is available.

Comment: yes. but i want to show to the user a message in the app, and i want to obligate to upgrade the app sometimes

Answer (score 3):

I found solution here about year ago. I cannot find a link now but there is it:

```
      String newVersion = Jsoup
                    .connect(
                            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                    + "Package" + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com").get()
                    .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]").first()
                    .ownText();
```

Require [Jsoup library](https://jsoup.org/).
here is the link of details answare [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309564/how-to-get-app-market-version-information-from-google-play-store)

Comment: They might present some sort of API i believe

Comment: @Shubham I believe too. Because when we don't have the native way for getting some ordinary app's information it's not comfortable.

Comment: can i do simple ajax call to get app version

Comment: using https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v2/java probably?

Comment: Hello. I have used above code in my app and it is live on play store for over a year. For past one month, this code returns null from API. Not sure what is wrong. Has this API stopped working..??

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the [`Edits.apks: upload`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/apks/upload) method which returns a version code for each APK you upload; you will use this version code to refer to the APK when you assign it to a track. Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks#apk_workflow_example).

This [unofficial API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) might also help as stated in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091534/checking-my-app-version-programmatically-in-android-market).

> Specifically, take a look at the Wiki page
>   [HowToSearchApps](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps).
>   The response to the query contains version information:
>
> ```
> {
>   "app": [
>     {
>       "rating": "4.642857142857143",
>       "title": "Ruboto IRB",
>       "ratingsCount": 14,
>       "creator": "Jan Berkel",
>       "appType": "APPLICATION",
>       "id": "9089465703133677000",
>       "packageName": "org.jruby.ruboto.irb",
>       "version": "0.1",
>       "versionCode": 1,
>       "creatorId": "\"Jan Berkel\"",
>       "ExtendedInfo": {
>         "category": "Tools",
>         "permissionId": [
> ...
> ```

Here are some related SO posts:

- [query the google play store for the version of an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470402/query-the-google-play-store-for-the-version-of-an-app)
- [How to get app market version information from google play store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309564/how-to-get-app-market-version-information-from-google-play-store)