# get play store app version in Ionic 2

Tags: android, ajax, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-play-services

I want to check app version which i have uploaded on playstore for force update. What should i do ? I tried to hit http request but getting cors issue and it will give result in html .
 I tried following api call

`this.http.get( "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moglix.vendor").subscribe(data => {
      alert(data);
    });`

I checked other solution like [How get the app version on the play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979931/how-get-the-app-version-on-the-play-storebut) it is not working for me.

I have alternative of rest api but i want to look into any functionality from play store only .

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this plugin: [Ionic Native App Update Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update/)

Using this plugin, you're able to check if an update is available for your application. Note: This requires a back-end to store the app version information, and should be updated simultaneously with your APK.

Comment: But in that we will create api to put app version which will check everytime for compare right ?

Comment: It is, as I noted.

Comment: hmm thanks but i get one link api  http://carreto.pt/tools/android-store-version/?package= . here we put package name and it will give json

Comment: and actually my api developer was not ready to create an api for this . if he was ready then i can easily do this , thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can use it in your ionic1 with angularjs projects:

```
$.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=--bundleID--", function(data){
            htmlContentsArray=$('<div/>').html(data).contents();
            htmlContents=htmlContentsArray['prevObject']['0']['childNodes']['141'].outerText;
            if(htmlContents == ''){
                htmlContents=htmlContentsArray['prevObject']['0']['childNodes']['144'].outerText;
            }
            latest_version_array=htmlContents.split('Current Version');
                var latest_version_string=latest_version_array['1'];
                var latest_version=latest_version_string.substr(0,5);
});
```